# Get FILE stream from File Handle

Tags: winapi

I would like to use file stream functions (e.g., "ftell") on an existing file I opened using CreateFile (which returns a HANDLE). I searched SO and elsewhere with no joy. I want to do something like this:

```
HANDLE h;
FILE *f;
int pos;
h = CreateFile( "MYFILE.TXT", ... )
f = *convert*( h, &f );    // the function I'm looking for  
pos = ftell( f );
```

**Is there a way to get a FILE stream from a file handle?**

Comment: `_open_osfhandle()` to travel to the 1970s, `_fdopen()` to teleport back to the 1980s

Comment: what sense in *ftell* ?

Comment: *"I would like to use file stream functions (e.g., "ftell")"* - Why would any one willingly want to do that? Why step back into POSIX, the Stone Age of computing, where files had a hard limit of 2GB?

Comment: Responders: I am maintaining a 15-year old legacy app built with VC6.0 wherein I can find no modern, politically correct solutions.  In any case, with all due respect, my question was "HOW" to do this, not "WHY" I shouldn't do this. BTW - The "HOW" is actually answered in the cited answer.

Comment: [`SetFilePointer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer) had always been available, no matter how legacy you claim your code to be, or whether you would need Visual C++ 6 to compile it.

Comment: My Bad, I see now that I SHOULD use SetFilePointer even in VC6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`_open_osfhandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-osfhandle) to create a C-style file descriptor from a Win32 `HANDLE`, and then use [`_fdopen()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fdopen-wfdopen) to create a `FILE*` from the file descriptor.